# How can I see the exception call stack in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, web-config, sharepoint-2010, callstack

I am trying to port a SharePoint 2007 site collection feature to 2010. During the feature activation, SharePoint shows the "yellow screen of death" stating "The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.".

AFAIK I have configured everything that is need to see the error:
in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config` I have set

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <compilation debug="true" />

<SharePoint>
  <SafeMode CallStack="true" />
```

(other attributes/tags ommited for brevity)

This was enough for SharePoint 2007 to display the full stack trace. Am I missing something for 2010?

Comment: I take it you've performed an iisreset??

Comment: Do you run your 2010 application in the same web application as c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80 ? I've done the exact same modifications as you (apart from compilation debug - i copy my PDB files manually), and it works fine.

@Shaneo: modifying web.config recycles the application pool, and an iisreset is unnecessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ran into this as well.  Had to modify web.config in 14 Root to enable it: set `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in file `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config` .

Comment: Thanks - updated your answer with the path that worked for me (editing CONFIG did not change anything).